# My order always get "Suspected Fraud" from paypal in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, paypal

I am trying to pay the order,but Magento 2 order always receiving the 'Suspected Fraud' and I am trying to get payment update,but always no new message.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution?